# Coldfusion extended component missing parameters

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, components, cfc

I'm trying to get a CFC (webCFC) with a remote function to return an instance of a different CFC (objCFC).

Here are the CFCs:

```
#webCFC
component { 
    remote function displayCFC(version=1) {
        if(version==1) {
            return new baseCFC();
        } else {
            return new objCFC();
        }
     }
 }

#baseCFC
component 
    accessors="true"
    persistent="true"
{
    property name="name" default="pete";    
}

#objCFC
component 
    extends="baseCFC"
    persistent="true"
    accessors="true"
{
    property name="age" default="30";
}
```

If I call this URL: **/webCFC.cfc?method=displayCFC&returnFormat=json**, I get this response:

```
{
"name" : "pete"
}
```

which is fine. If I call this URL: **/webCFC.cfc?method=displayCFC&returnFormat=json&version=2**, then the response is missing the property from *baseCFC*

```
{
"age" : 30
}
```

I would expect the response to look like this:

```
{
"name" : "pete",
"age" : 30
}
```

I know that I can use the setName() and getName() functions on objCFC, it is definatly extending *baseCFC* but the extended properties don't show if I access the CFC through the browser.

Is it possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the `seralizejson` bug (not sure when will it ever be bug free).

A workaround would be to implement your own `getMemento()` or `toJSON()` method that returns all the desired properties in a struct.  Then `serializeJSON` that struct instead.

Comment: I did wonder if it was to do with JSON, but if I just do a writeDump in the page, it doesn't show the properties there either. But you're right, if this is a bug then I'll have to loop over the properties and output them manually